# Google Apps Script File Upload, Save to Google Sheets, Form Submit without file

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications, upload

I am trying to build a apps script web app which should collect bunch of information from users, save it in a google sheet and accept file uploads to google drive. However uses should also be able to submit it without any attachment.

What is working?
1. The following code accepts user data and saves in a google sheet. However file upload doesn't work
2. If I remove the "function iteratorFileUpload()" and run "function UploadFile()" on "onclick" event of the input type submit button then single file upload works, however in that scenario form submit without file upload doesn't work.
3. I have also tried multiple file uploads but it doesn't seem to work either.

code.gs

```
var emailTo= "******@gmail.com"
var REDIRECT_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/*******/dev";


function doGet() {
  var ssheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NNW0cx-9niPDwkNmQXWdY0KjXnP0Ihjo0ZoIM6ckkDM/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssheet_url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Inputs")
  var mylistTransactionType = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getRange("A2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var mylistWhoRecieved = ws.getRange(2,2,ws.getRange("B2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var mylistTransactionProfile = ws.getRange(2,3,ws.getRange("B2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var mylistSourceOfFund = ws.getRange(2,4,ws.getRange("B2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();


  var htmlmylistTransactionTypeArray = mylistTransactionType.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
  var htmlmylistWhoRecievedArray = mylistWhoRecieved.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
  var htmlmylistTransactionProfileArray = mylistTransactionProfile.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
  var htmlmylistmylistSourceOfFundArray = mylistSourceOfFund.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');


  //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('InputForm.html');
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  tmp.title = "Transaction Record Web APP";
  //tmp.mylist1 = mylist1.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  tmp.mylistTransactionType = htmlmylistTransactionTypeArray;
  tmp.mylistWhoRecieved = htmlmylistWhoRecievedArray;
  tmp.mylistTransactionProfile = htmlmylistTransactionProfileArray;
  tmp.mylistSourceOfFund = htmlmylistmylistSourceOfFundArray;


  return tmp.evaluate().addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');


}


function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();

}

function doPost(e) {

 try {
    var data = e.parameter.fileContent;
    var filename = e.parameter.filename;
    var email = e.parameter.Transcation_Profile;
    var name = e.parameter.Who_Recieved_Paid;
    var result=uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data,filename,name,email,e);
    return redirect();

   // ContentService    // return json success results
         // .createTextOutput(
           // JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                          //  "data": JSON.stringify(result) }))
          //.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { return redirect(); // if error return this
   // Logger.log(error);
    //return ContentService
          //.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          //.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } return redirect();

}

function redirect() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    "<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + REDIRECT_URL + "\";</script>"
  ); 
}

// new property service GLOBAL
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
// see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

/**
 * select the sheet
 */
//function setup() {
//    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
//}

/**
 * record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
 * e is the data received from the POST
 */

function record_data(e,fileUrl) {
  try {
//    var doc     = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var doc     = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1NNW0cx-9niPDwkNmQXWdY0KjXnP0Ihjo0ZoIM6ckkDM");


    var sheet   = doc.getSheetByName('responses'); // select the responses sheet

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row     = [ new Date() ]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp
    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column

      if(headers[i].length > 0 && headers[i] == "Invoice") {
        row.push(fileUrl); // add data to row
      }
      else if(headers[i].length > 0) {
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); // add data to row
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
  finally {
    return;
  }

}

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, name, email,e) {
  try {
    var dropbox = "Demo";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);
        var file = folder.createFolder([name, email].join("-")).createFile(blob);

        var fileUrl=file.getUrl();

        //Generating Email Body
        var html =  
    '<body>' + 
      '<h2> New Job Application </h2>' +
        '<p>Name : '+e.parameters.name+'</p>' +
        '<p>Email : '+e.parameters.email+'</p>' +
        '<p>Contact : '+e.parameters.contact+'</p>' +
        '<p>Skill Sets : '+e.parameters.skillsets+'</p>' +
        '<p>LinkedIn Url : '+e.parameters.linkedinUrl+'</p>' +
        '<p>File Name  : '+e.parameters.filename+'</p>' +
        '<p><a href='+file.getUrl()+'>Resume Link</a></p><br />' +
    '</body>';

    record_data(e,fileUrl);

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, "New Job Application Recieved","New Job Application Request Recieved",{htmlBody:html});
        return file.getUrl();
  } catch (f) {
    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"file upload failed",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(f) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

     <?!= include("page-css"); ?>   

  </head>

  <!--<body onload="addList()">  Modified -->
  <body>

<div class="container">

    <blockquote>
     <h5><?= title; ?></h5>
    </blockquote>



        <form id="uploadForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxZeCebav4lkFNiMrOFa9PYaWTMkT4LA7-xHqMOc_k74BDWlyEB/exec" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="fileContent" id="fileContent">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="filename" id="filename">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">face</i>

        <input list="dropdownList1" name="Who_Recieved_Paid" placeholder="Who Recieved or Paid" required> <!-- Modified -->
            <datalist id="dropdownList1"> 
             <?!= mylistWhoRecieved; ?>

          </datalist>        


        <!--<input required type="text" value="" name="Who_Recieved_Paid" id="Who_Recieved_Paid" class="validate">        

        <label class="active" for="Who_Recieved_Paid"> Who Recieved or Paid : </label> -->
      </div>


      <div class="input-field col s6">   
        <i class="material-icons prefix">business</i> 
        <input list="dropdownList2" name="Transaction_Type" placeholder="Transaction Type" required> <!-- Modified -->
            <datalist id="dropdownList2"> 
             <?!= mylistTransactionType; ?>

          </datalist>

      </div>      

   </div><!-- First Row Form -->

   <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6"> 
        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_balance</i>

        <input list="dropdownList3" name="Source_of_Fund" placeholder="Source of Fund" required> <!-- Modified -->
            <datalist id="dropdownList3"> 
             <?!= mylistSourceOfFund; ?>

          </datalist>        

        <!-- <input required type="text" value="" name="Source_of_Fund" id="Source_of_Fund" class="validate">
        <label class="active" for="Source_of_Fund"> Source of Fund : </label> -->
      </div>  

      <div class="input-field col s6">                   
        <i class="material-icons prefix">attach_money</i>
        <input required type="text" value="" name="Amount" id="Amount" class="validate">
        <label class="active" for="Amount"> Amount :</label> 
      </div>
   </div><!-- 2nd Row Form -->

   <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">            
        <i class="material-icons prefix">menu</i>

        <input list="dropdownList4" name="Transcation_Profile" placeholder="Transcation Profile" required> <!-- Modified -->
            <datalist id="dropdownList4"> 
             <?!= mylistTransactionProfile; ?>

          </datalist>                

        <!--<input required type="text" value="" name="Transcation_Profile" id="Transcation_Profile" class="validate">
        <label class="active" for="Transcation_Profile"> Transcation Profile :</label>  -->
      </div>




        <div class="input-field col s6">      
          <input id="prefDate" type="text" class="datepicker">
          <label for="prefDate" >Transaction Date</label>
        </div><!-- Close Date -->


   </div><!-- 3rd Row Form -->   


     <div class="row">


      <div class="input-field col s12">         
        <i class="material-icons prefix">chat_bubble</i>
        <input type="text" value="" name="Remarks" id="Remarks" class="validate"> 
        <label class="active" for="Remarks"> Remarks :</label>
      </div>


      </div><!-- 4th Row Form -->   

</form>


   <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <div class="file-upload">
          <div class="file-select">
            <div class="file-select-button" id="fileName">Choose File</div>
            <div class="file-select-name" id="noFile">No file chosen...</div> 
            <input type="file" name="attach" id="attach">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

   </div><!-- 5th Row Form -->  


   <div class="row">
<!--<input required id="attach" name="attach" type="file"/> -->

      <div class="input-field col s6"> 
        <input value="Submit" type="button" class="btn orange darken-2" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()" />
      </div>

   </div><!-- 6th Row Form -->   

</div><!-- Close Container -->


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>  
  <?!= include("page-js"); ?>  
  </body>
</html>
```

page-js.html

In this page I have all the java scripts. Above mentioned functions are here.

```
<script>


          //Date Picker Initialization
          var datePicker = document.getElementById('prefDate');
          M.Datepicker.init(datePicker,{
          showClearBtn:true,          
          });


    function iteratorFileUpload() {
        var allFiles = document.getElementById('attach').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
            } else {

    // Send each file one at a time
    var i=0;
    for (i=0; i < allFiles.total; i+=1) {
      console.log('This iteration: ' + i);
      UploadFile(allFiles[i]);
          };
        };
      };



function UploadFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  //var file = document.getElementById('attach').files[0];


  reader.onload = function(){


    document.getElementById('fileContent').value=reader.result;
    document.getElementById('filename').value=file.name;
    document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);



}



$('#attach').bind('change', function () {
  var filename = $("#attach").val();
  if (/^\s*$/.test(filename)) {
    $(".file-upload").removeClass('active');
    $("#noFile").text("No file chosen..."); 
  }
  else {
    $(".file-upload").addClass('active');
    $("#noFile").text(filename.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")); 
  }
});


</script>
```

p.s - I am new to all this and this is my firs app. I have collected sample codes from SO, YouTube and other sites and did some modifications. I have some prior experience with vba but only the basics. So, please expect silly mistakes.

Comment: Follow steps to provide [mcve]

Comment: Hello @NovemberRain, can you please be more precise on where do you encounter the issue? So if I understood correctly, you are not able to **upload** the wanted file? Cheers!